# Can I buy a remote for a ceiling fan that will not turn off. Remote missing when purchased home

Tags: ceiling-fan

We just got our keys to our home and in one of the bedrooms the ceiling fan is on with no pull chains, no remote and switch does not control the on/off of fan.  What should we do?

Comment: Contact your agent to see if they can get the remote from the previous owners.

Comment: I'd definitely contact agent -- this seems like something similar to changing fixtures after the sale (not allowed). Chances are the previous owner just packed the remote by mistake. Next alternative is to find the model and see if you can order a new one from the manufacturer.

Comment: In the meantime, your alternatives are to: (1) hardwire in a regular or universal fan-control wall switch (if there's a blank faceplate in the room, this is probably very simple). (2) Turn off the power at the breaker, though, this will almost certainly affect plugs in this room and/or lights in other rooms. (3) Take the fan down and disconnect the power in the junction box, which will effectively make the fan unusable until you reconnect the wire.

Answer (score 1):

you could always add a remote module

[http://www.amazon.com/Universal-Ceiling-Fan-Remote-Control/dp/B001I1M95E](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001I1M95E)

i would take a look why the switch doesn't work properly

example see if it's connected to the switch or bypassed